# Overwrite just a part of the file in bash

Tags: bash

I can't seem to figure out how to overwrite a part of a file. For example,

```
echo -n "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" > file
echo -n "1234567890" > file
cat file
1234567890
```

and

```
echo -n "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" > file
echo -n "1234567890" >> file
cat file
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890
```

How do I get

```
1234567890klmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

I'm going to end up doing this with two files, but I wanted to show the concept with a string, too. Would `dd` work for this?

Comment: I don't think `bash` has a built-in way to open a file in overwrite mode like that. Usually you use something like `sed` to do it.

Comment: Yes, Bash does have a built-in method for doing this.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `file2` contains '1234567890' and `file` contains 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', you can do:

```
> dd conv=notrunc if=file2 of=file

> cat file
1234567890klmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: I found a link with relevant discussion: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146922/is-dd-able-to-overwrite-parts-of-a-file

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using Bash primitives, just like you asked.  No need for external programs.  The problem with `>` is that it causes truncation of the target file.  Instead you should open the file for simultaneous reading and writing; this makes Bash skip the truncation step.

```
echo -n "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" > temp.txt
exec 3<> temp.txt   # open file descriptor 3 for reading and writing
echo -n "1234567890" >&3  # write to fd3
exec 3<&-  # close fd3 for reading
exec 3>&-  # close fd3 for writing
```

Learn everything you never wanted to know about I/O redirection in Bash [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `sed`:

```
$ echo -n "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" > file
$ sed -i "1s/^.\{10\}/1234567890/" file
$ cat file
1234567890klmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Or, more generally (without having to hardcode the length):

```
$ echo -n "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" > file
$ str="1234567890"
$ sed -i "1s/^.\{${#str}\}/$str/" file
$ cat file
1234567890klmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `tail`:

```
# write the inital file
echo -n "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" > file
# set the input string  variable (just for readability)
inp="1234567890";
# replace <length of inp> characters in original file
# by concatenating $inp with tail's output (need to add 1)
echo ${inp}$(tail -c +$((${#inp}+1)) file) > file
```

I think `tail` should always be considered when you need an end of a file, which is really what this problem boils down to.